# Show/hide function with multiple div ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know close to nothing about jQuery, but I swear I'm trying to learn. The thing is, I've got some code that works, but I know it's repetitive and probably not kosher for a real programmer, which is why I've turned to you all.

What I want to do is show/hide (or toggle, whatever you think is best) some informational divs, or so you might call them, on [this page](http://vefmomentum.com/events/).

The show/hide code that I have right now stands at this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#meet_growlab, #buddy_tv').hide();

    $('a#growlab').click(function(){
    $('#meet_growlab').show('slow');
});

    $('a#growlab_close').click(function(){
    $('#meet_growlab').hide('slow');
})

    $('a#buddytv').click(function(){
    $('#buddy_tv').show('slow');
});

    $('a#buddytv_close').click(function(){
    $('#buddy_tv').hide('slow');
})


});
```

With the HTML being:

```
<div id="meet_growlab">BLAH BLAH BLAH
<p><a href="#" id="growlab_close">Close</a></p>
</div>

<div id="buddy_tv">BLAH BLAH BLAH
<p><a href="#" id="buddytv_close">Close</a></p>
</div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="growlab" rel="#meet_growlab">Meet GrowLab - Canada’s Y-Combinator Arrives in Vancouver (June 24, 2011)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="buddytv" rel="#buddy_tv">Building the Web's Best Entertainment-Based Community Site: Andy Liu, CEO and Founder of BuddyTV (April 1, 2011)</a></li>
</ul>
```

It works, but it's not pretty.

Answer (score 2):

1. You could have the hide/show divs inside a container, and then on `.ready` hide all its immediate children;
2. You could then target all `a.close` inside this container, and on click hide the clicked anchor's grand-grandparent;
3. And finally target all anchors inside the items list, and on click show the div corresponding to the anchor's `rel`;
4. I would also make the anchor's `href` the same as its `rel`, so that if any user has JavaScript disabled the anchor still works.

So, HTML:

```
<div id="eventDescriptions">
  <div id="meet_growlab">BLAH BLAH BLAH
    <p><a href="#growlab" class="close">Close</a></p>
  </div>
  <div id="buddy_tv">BLAH BLAH BLAH
    <p><a href="#buddytv" class="close">Close</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<ul id="eventTitles">
    <li><a href="#" id="growlab" rel="#meet_growlab">Meet GrowLab - Canada’s Y-Combinator Arrives in Vancouver (June 24, 2011)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="buddytv" rel="#buddy_tv">Building the Web's Best Entertainment-Based Community Site: Andy Liu, CEO and Founder of BuddyTV (April 1, 2011)</a></li>
</ul>
```

and a more compact and `DRY` JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#eventDescriptions>div').hide();
  $('#eventTitles a').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(target).show('slow');
  });

  $('#eventDescriptions .close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().hide('slow');
  })
});
```

Here, a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QYjLY/

---

Other things I quickly noticed:

1. Good job on using rel;
2. Instead of `<img border=0 ...` you could use CSS - `a img { border: 0;}`;
3. `#social` is a list, so it could be a `ul` instead of a `div`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips ANeves! And as for #social being a list - even when it's not incorporating the li tag to bring about different elements it's still considered a list? I thought it was just a div because it's a bunch of images, and not text...

Comment: I should probably be more eloquent in my question, namely if I'm displaying a set of images, one after another in a horizontal line, that's a list? Isn't it just more code to add a ul component? I have to have div anyway for the social media buttons to position it correct relative to the nav menu and sub menu and the news ticker. Plus those images aren't really even a list - just a conglomeration of...well, images.

Comment: I think I should have used `could` instead of the strong `should`. My thought was that abstractly it is a list of... other presences on the web? So it could be a `ul`, then styled to be shown in a line. Not too important, though.

Comment: Aha. I get it. Thanks for the clarification and thanks for all the help!